# Is there a way to articulate "giving up" or "acknowledging defeat" in 1 word?

Tags: verbs

I tried Google and looking around already, but having trouble with the terminology to continue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about *surrender* in a conflict, or some other context?

Comment: In the _surrender_ context.

Comment: You can often find phrasal verbs like *give up* in various [dictionaries](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_up) (*surrender, quit, relinquish, forlet, abandon...*) and [thesauruses](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/give%20up) (*capitulate, knuckle under, submit, succumb...*).

Comment: 'How about 'uncle'?

Answer (score 4):

How about *concede?* Usually used like this: "I concede" or "He conceded defeat."

Comment: Good one! I think this is by far the best word from all answers and comments, because it embodies all the relevant meaning, without significant special nuances. An army could *condede [defeat]* in a war - but one could equally, for example, *concede [a fine point]* in the context of a low-key dispute with someone over some detail of usage here on ELU. Most alternatives don't sit so comfortably across the whole gamut of contexts.

Answer (score 2):

How about "yield?" It's a bit old-fashioned, but has the right connotation.